# TsconfigPathsPlugin type not compatible with webpack 5

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-5

I'm trying to upgrade to webpack 5, but I'm now getting a type error when
trying to use the TsconfigPathsPlugin. (npm tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin).

I need this plugin so that I can resolve the alias paths in my files. You can see a usage example here: https://betterprogramming.pub/the-right-usage-of-aliases-in-webpack-typescript-4418327f47fa

```js
resolve: {
    extensions: [...],

    // resolve aliases from tsconfig.server.json
    plugins: [
      new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ // type error here
        configFile: './tsconfig.server.json',
      }),
    ],

    alias: {...},
},
```

I get the following error:

```
Type 'TsconfigPathsPlugin' is not assignable to type '"..." | ResolvePluginInstance'.
Type 'TsconfigPathsPlugin' is not assignable to type 'ResolvePluginInstance'.
Types of property 'apply' are incompatible.
```

I have the feeling that this isn't a widespread issue as I can't see any mention
of it in other places, but I would have thought that I'd be able to find at least someone
that has come across the same problem.

Comment: The most recent version seems to work fine. The type error suggests you may have a string `'...'` somewhere in your configuration.

Comment: Hmm, I have the most recent version of both. `"..."` is a valid option (type) to pass into `plugins` now in webpack 5, that is you could say `plugins: [ "...", new CssMinimizer(), ]` and this will include terser plugin whereas it used to overwrite it and you had to manually add it back in before'. So that error is saying `TsconfigPathsPlugin is not assignable to "..."`, not that I'm trying to use `"..."` anywhere.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. In that case I don't have any suggestions, other than wiping `node_modules`, and maybe try creating a fresh `package-lock.json`.

Comment: @Oblosys tried that too unfortunately. I've downgraded webpack in the meantime, I'm sure I'll come back in a few minor versions and something will get it going :shrug: Thanks anyway

Comment: Did you find a solution? Having the same problems with `BundleAnalyzerPlugin`

Comment: @breezertwo, I did not unfortunately, I ended up downgrading to webpack 4

Comment: @BrettEast If you give it an other try in the future, try to wrap the plugin. `(new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ // type error here
        configFile: './tsconfig.server.json',
      }) as unknown) as ResolvePluginInstance.` This did the trick for me. It's due to some unfinished types of the plugins

Comment: I think I had the same problem and I ended up casting the resulting plugin instance into correct type and it seemed to work fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, but today I found the plugin works under below versions.

```
"tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.1",
"webpack": "^5.51.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue but use the below version:

```
"tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.1",
"webpack": "^5.9.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

if this doesn't work try this combination

```
"tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.0",
"webpack": "^5.51.1",
```